# SQL Server: how to update a row if there is other rows having all same values in all fields as this row?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

If a table is like the following in SQL Server, how do I update the first row?

```
     Name  |  Value  
    -------+---------
     Test  |  VALUE1 
     Test  |  VALUE1 
     Test  |  VALUE1 
     Test  |  VALUE1 
     Test  |  VALUE1
```

Comment: is there any id field in your table?

Comment: You shouldn't store duplicate rows. You shouldn't even be allowed to store duplicate rows. Tip of today: Primary keys and unique constraints!

Comment: No ID field @fa06. The primary key is Name+Value

Comment: My colleague created this table... I won't do this kind of things...

Comment: if primary key is Name+Value then your table should not take duplicate values

Comment: Yeah I don't know, I just tired and i have successfully created 4 duplicated rows.

Comment: then you can delete those duplicate rows? what is your purpose of updateing the first row as you don't even identiy which is your first from these rows

Comment: Actually I want to put *Monday* into one filed in the 1st row, *Tuesday* in the 2nd, and so on. I think I can delete them all. I am just curious how can I just update one record.

Comment: BTW, tables have _columns_, not fields. (A field in SQL is something else.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `row_number()`

```
 with cte as
( select *,row_number() over(partition by Test order by VALUE1) rn from tab
) update cte set name=val ,value=val where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the given sample data, another approach can be using `UPDATE TOP (1)` like following.

```
 update top (1) t
 set name='changed', value='changed'
 from table_name t
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/LUAWT26046)